# ./src/App.js Module not found: Can't resolve '@material-ui/data-grid' in xxx

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datagrid, material-ui

I build a react+flask app and I want to use Material-UI
I tested the button and it works and I need a data grid, a table and I get this error:

```
./src/App.js
Module not found: Can't resolve '@material-ui/data-grid' in 'C:\spvreact\react-flask-app\src'
```

And in the console I get this:

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module '@material-ui/data-grid'
at webpackMissingModule (App.css?4433:45)
at Module../src/App.js (App.css?4433:45)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:784)
at fn (bootstrap:150)
at Module../src/index.js (index.css?f3f6:45)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:784)
at fn (bootstrap:150)
at Object.1 (serviceWorker.js:141)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:784)
at checkDeferredModules (bootstrap:45)
at Array.webpackJsonpCallback [as push] (bootstrap:32)
at main.chunk.js:1
```

This is the code:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import { DataGrid } from '@material-ui/data-grid';




function App() {

const columns = [
{ field: 'id', headerName: 'ID', width: 70 },
{ field: 'firstName', headerName: 'First name', width: 130 },
{ field: 'lastName', headerName: 'Last name', width: 130 },
{
  field: 'age',
  headerName: 'Age',
  type: 'number',
  width: 90,
},
{
  field: 'fullName',
  headerName: 'Full name',
  description: 'This column has a value getter and is not sortable.',
  sortable: false,
  width: 160,
  valueGetter: (params) =>
    `${params.getValue('firstName') || ''} ${
      params.getValue('lastName') || ''
    }`,
  },
  ];

const rows = [
{ id: 1, lastName: 'Snow', firstName: 'Jon', age: 35 },
{ id: 2, lastName: 'Lannister', firstName: 'Cersei', age: 42 },
{ id: 3, lastName: 'Lannister', firstName: 'Jaime', age: 45 },
{ id: 4, lastName: 'Stark', firstName: 'Arya', age: 16 },
{ id: 5, lastName: 'Targaryen', firstName: 'Daenerys', age: null },
{ id: 6, lastName: 'Melisandre', firstName: null, age: 150 },
{ id: 7, lastName: 'Clifford', firstName: 'Ferrara', age: 44 },
{ id: 8, lastName: 'Frances', firstName: 'Rossini', age: 36 },
{ id: 9, lastName: 'Roxie', firstName: 'Harvey', age: 65 },
];

useEffect(() => {
fetch('http://127.0.0.1:5000/formular',{
headers : { 
'Content-Type': 'application/json',
'Accept': 'application/json'
}

}).then(response =>
response.json().then(data =>{
console.log(data);
})
);
},[]);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
return <div className="App">
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/@material-ui/core@latest/umd/material-ui.development.js" ></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css? 
  family=Roboto:300,400,500,700&display=swap" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" />
  
  

  <div style={{ height: 400, width: '100%' }}>
      <DataGrid rows={rows} columns={columns} pageSize={5} checkboxSelection />
    </div>
  
  </div>;

  }

  export default App;
```

I tried in cmd npm install @material-ui next or something like that but it still doesn`t import the grid.

Please help

Comment: Have tried re-installing packages? have you correctly installed the `'@material-ui/data-grid'` package?

Comment: Thanks it works, I thought that if I downloaded @material-ui it would download all components.

Answer (score 32):

Data-grid does not come included with the core installation of material-ui.

Install data-grid with:

```
npm install @material-ui/data-grid
```

Import it with:

```
import { DataGrid } from '@material-ui/data-grid'
```

Answer (score 9):

Data grid does not come with default installation.
Refer [here](https://material-ui.com/components/data-grid/)

You can install it seperately as:

```
npm install @material-ui/data-grid
```

And import it as

```
import { DataGrid } from '@material-ui/data-grid';
```

Comment: It should be 
`npm install --save @material-ui/data-grid`

Answer (score 7):

follow these steps:

1. install the core material-ui

   `npm install @material-ui/core`
2. now intall the data-gird

   `npm install @material-ui/data-grid`
3. that show have done the deal!

Answer (score 0):

I also had to change react and react-dom to v17.0.0 in package.json

"react": "^17.0.0"

"react-dom": "^17.0.0"

Answer (score 0):

It means some of the packages/dependencies are missing from the node-modules

To fix this
`npm install <missing-package-name>`

In your case it is
`npm install @material-ui/data-grid`

Answer (score 0):

Use this for importing Grid. This solved mine,

```
import Grid from '@material-ui/core';
```

Also it works for Material-ui Box, Paper, Link, styled all of them.
Use like this,

```
import { Grid, Link, makeStyles, Paper,Box, styled} from '@material-ui/core';
```